# Hiding a Visualforce button depending on a field value

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm looking for a way to hide a button depending on the field value.

My goal here is that the button will be hidden IF Product_Family__c is EQUAL to "Services".

Apex

```
public Opportunity currentOpportunity {get; set;}
public void getOppty(){
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Id, Product_Family__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=: currentOpportunity.Id];  

    }
```

VF

```
            <apex:commandButton styleClass="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-m-top_large"
                                value="Add Item" action="{!addItemRow}" reRender="tableId" status="status" render="{!getOppty}">
            </apex:commandButton>
```

I'm still missing the criteria for the APEX, any ideas?

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: What does the rest of your VF page look like?  Is it using the opportunity standard controller?

Comment: @NickCook Yes, it's using the opportunity standard controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the `rendered` parameter on the `apex:commanButton` element.

e.g.

```
<apex:commandButton rendered="{!Opportunity.Product_Family__c != 'Services'}" value="Add Item" action="{!addItemRow}" reRender="tableId" status="status" />
```

You don't need any apex code if all you want to do is control whether the buttons is displayed on page load.

Comment: I overthink. It's so simple thank you very much!